# Open the watch window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am looking for the watch window in eclipse. It is not obvious where it is and my google search yielded no fruit. would someone be able to tell me how to open the watch window?

Comment: Do you mean the "Expressions" view for watch expressions? You find that in the Debug perspective or with Show view->Debug->Expressions.

Comment: @achim if that is similar to the watch window in visual studio then yes.

Comment: Can you describe that functionality?

Comment: Sure, it allows you to see variables you specify and their properties as the code runs in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse that view is called Expressions - for watch expressions. It opens regularly with the Debug view, but you can open it using "Window"->"Show view"->"Other"->"Debug"->"Expressions".